# \u7f continually keeps inserting itself into my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

Less of a code help question, but an explanation. I keep having the unicode character \u7f insterted into my code but I'm not doing anything to add it. Do I need to encode my JS or something similar? I can't stop my JS warning me Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. Screenshot attached: https://ibb.co/fX3MMT.
Blog seems to have my problem too (I use Sublime) but his fix didn't work for me: http://codebuckets.com/2017/03/10/dealing-with-invalid-js-characters-in-vs-code/

Comment: Are you positive the dot is actually being added and not just a visual thing? What happens if you save the file with the dots shown and then open the file in a simple text editor app? Are the dots still present?

Comment: Yeah, it's being added and has the unicode character \u7f. In a text editor its present, it just becomes a []

Comment: What about checking your installed plugins? Maybe try disabling them all, then re-enabling 1 at a time?

Comment: I don't have any plug ins, though that's a good idea if I did

Comment: @kea Have you tried a different editor?

Comment: @Bergi trying now thank you

Comment: @Bergi VS Code does it also. I must have something poorly formed

Comment: or your editor is not the only program changing the file